# OnsenUI: Carousel does not update on orientation change

Tags: carousel, onsen-ui

I am working with fullscreen OnsenUI carousel. The issue is when I swipe/change carousel item and then change the orientation OR resize the window, it does not look good. This issue is with the official OnsenUI carousel example as well.

[image]

This is the code I am following:

```
<ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen initial-index="1" var="carousel">
    <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: gray;">
      <div class="item-label">GRAY</div>
    </ons-carousel-item>
    <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #085078;">
      <div class="item-label">BLUE</div>
    </ons-carousel-item>
    <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #373B44;">
      <div class="item-label">DARK</div>
    </ons-carousel-item>
    <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #D38312;">
      <div class="item-label">ORANGE</div>
    </ons-carousel-item>
    <ons-carousel-cover>
      <div class="cover-label">Swipe left or right</div>
    </ons-carousel-cover>
  </ons-carousel>
</ons-page>
```

[This](http://codepen.io/onsen/full/xbbzOQ/) is the Pen from the OnsenUI site.

**NOTE**: I am using OnsenUI version 1.3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it behaves this way due to a cached value of the item size. The fix requires some hacks with the internal Onsen carousel behaviour, however the development of Onsen 1 is finished, so doing some hacks like these should be safe. What you need to do on a resize event to fix it is the following:

```
  var i = carousel._scroll / carousel._currentElementSize;
  delete carousel._currentElementSize;
  carousel.setActiveCarouselItemIndex(i);
```

Here's a [**demo**](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/mPNMOZ?editors=1011) with the fix applied.

If you're using angular then you can just use the `var="carousel"` attribute and you will be able to use `carousel` in your controller.

If you don't like angular then selecting it is a little tricky, but not impossible:

```
var carousel = angular.element(document.getElementById('carousel')).data('ons-carousel');
```

Hope this helped.

Alternatively you could just switch to Onsen 2, where such problems can be fixed quickly in the framework itself.

**Update:**

This bug is fixed in Onsen 2.

Comment: Related: https://community.onsen.io/topic/424/changing-the-width-of-browser-window-does-not-change-the-scroll-width-of-onsen-carousel-onsen-ui-2/3